# Как сделать вот такой скрипт для Cheapshot?

Tags: javascript, java, ios, бот

Ребят, нужна помощь!

Есть AutoTouch на IOS. Язык использует Java и суть бота проста. При входе в игру (Cheapshot) активизируется скрипт, который находит определённую движущуюся цель (может по цветам пикселей) и убивает ее, после уничижения цели, приходят ещё несколько и т.д. По сути бот для того, чтобы фармить.

Т.е скрипт находит, убивает, подбирает опыт и так в цикле до того момента пока пользователь сам не остановит этот процесс.

P.S на картинке цель скрипта, увеличенная
[image: вот увеличенная картинка жертвы нужного скрипта]

Comment: Андрей, напишите вашу банковскую карту, я вам перечислю денег, чтобы вам было проще писать код

Comment: Неплохая шутка, Михаил.